# Amamzon ATHENA: no viable alternative at input 'create external'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am using following DDL query to create table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS poi_test1(  
  'taxonomy_level_1' string,
  'taxonomy_level_2' string,
  'taxonomy_level_3' string,
  'taxonomy_level_4' string,
  'poi_name' string,
  'mw_segment_name' string,
  'latitude' double,
  'longitude' double,
  'city' string,
  'state' string,
  'country_code' string,
  'default_radius' float
  ) 
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

LOCATION
  's3://mw.test/jishan1/qa1/poi1';
```

Error:  line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'create external' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 5dbd0eb8-6842-45ca-8f60-9f17fd2e4c04)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove single quotes around columns or enclose them in backticks if reserved keywords present and in double quotes if column starts with digit.
Read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html) for naming conventions to be used with Athena.

I ran your query as shown below by removing single quotes and it created table successfully

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE poi_test1(  
  taxonomy_level_1 string,
  taxonomy_level_2 string,
  taxonomy_level_3 string,
  taxonomy_level_4 string,
  poi_name string,
  mw_segment_name string,
  latitude double,
  longitude double,
  city string,
  state string,
  country_code string,
  default_radius float
  ) 
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION's3://mw.test/jishan1/qa1/poi1';
```

Comment: Thanks Prabhakar for your comment. i have also ran the previous query and executed successfully. don't know what was happening previously.

Comment: @JishanAlam you ran a query with single quotes around column names and it ran successfully ? Well it didn't ran in my case then when I ran the same exact query that you posted in your question.

Comment: Yes. i have made slight changes in serde

Comment: ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://mw.test/jishan1/qa1/poi1/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');

Comment: the query that I gave also uses LazySimpleSerDe by default. You can try creating a table with DDL I posted and do show create table <table name>.